# formatnumber add commas every time how?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I force FormatNumber to use a "-" to separate every "000"

Depending on my users culture on their computer
the result looks like "123 456 789.1235" or "123,456,789.1235"

How do I force it

```
Dim A As Decimal = "123456789.123456" 

Dim B As String = FormatNumber(A, 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew said, but if you want spaces (or dashes) you can just insert them in place of the commas.

```
Dim a As Decimal = 123456789.123456D
Dim b As String = If(a < 0,"-","") & a.ToString("### ### ### ### ##0.####").Trim(" ")
'Dim b As String = If(a < 0,"-","") & a.ToString("###-###-###-###-##0.####").Trim("-")
```

Notice the trim statement.  It removes any leading characters that may show up due to the length of a.  I do like @Subs routine though, because it can handle a regardless of length.  This one you have to put enough placeholders (#) in to deal with it.

Comment: What about .Trim("-") when a is negative?

Comment: @Andrew, you got me. didn't take that into account. Perhaps wrap an if statement around it that says if a is <0 then append a dash to the front?  Editing entry with an IIF statement to do so.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I did mean to use If instead of IIf; coding in VBA today and am in a different mindset.  Updated code above.  But that is my last one; OP needs to take some initiative.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for .ToString, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ce53cfb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Thus:

```
Dim a As Decimal = 123456789.123456D
Dim b As String = a.ToString("###,##0.####")
```

Please look up how to set **Option Strict On**, because you have tried to assign a string to a decimal value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are lots of ways to do it. If you want to insert spaces then @Andrew way would not work but it is simple. This is a way if you try will motivate you do write your own coding.

```
    Dim a As Decimal = 123456789.123456D
    Dim i As Integer = a.IndexOf(".")
    Dim b As String = a.Substring(i)    
    Dim sep As String = " "   
    For j As Integer = i - 3 To 0 Step -3
        If j > 0 Then
            b = sep + a.Substring(j, 3) + b
        End If
        If j < 3 Then
            If j = 0 Then
                b = a.Substring(0, 3) + b
            Else
                b = a.Substring(0, j) + b
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If i < 3 Then
        b = a.Substring(0, i) + b
    End If
```

Note :  `sep=","` or `" "` or `anything you want`  and  the last `if` statement deals with cases where `i-3 < 0`

Comment: Yes, the OP is a little confusing in that the title says "formatnumber add commas..." and yet in the first line of the body it asks about adding "-". And "," and "-" are not even close on any keyboard I've seen.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yeah, I am trying to motivate him to write his own coding instead of asking help for simple things